# Communicate with ZigBee device via WiFi

Tags: wifi, zigbee

I'm working on some software to manage a device that communicates with a remote control via ZigBee. We would like the device to be able to communicate with a web server and/or smartphone via Wi-Fi, so that our software can interact with it. The ZigBee remote is clunky and we are trying to replace and automate some of the functionality.

I'm wondering if something like this: [Sparkfun WiFly Module](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10822)
or this: [Digi Xbee WiFi](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/point-multipoint-rfmodules/xbee-wi-fi#overview)
might be able to help me achieve this.

Forgive me if this is a silly question; I'm pretty unfamiliar with ZigBee and its related hardware. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify, what I want to do is swap the current remote for an iPad. The board has an XBee Pro module and there is another one located in the current remote.

I'm thinking it would be best to swap the XBee Pro with one of the Wi-Fi modules mentioned above, and reprogram the board to communicate with an iPad via an ad-hoc network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a hardware design that has an XBee 20-pin socket on it you absolutely can change it out for an XBee WiFi module and then communicate with your device via an iPad or a web-server.

Here is a [link to the XBee WiFi](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/point-multipoint-rfmodules/xbee-wi-fi#overview).

If, on the other hand, you want to be able to communicate with your XBee ZB/ZigBee device from a smart phone or from an external web application you can use the following solutions pattern:

[ Web Site/Smart Phone ] - - - (Device Cloud) - - - [XBee Gateway] - - - [ XBee or ZigBee Device ]

The XBee Gateway can be a device like an [Digi ConnectPort X](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-routers-gateways/gateways/connectportx2gateways#overview) gateway or something of your own design that can speak TCP/IP and ZigBee simultaneously.  The gateway then creates a TCP/IP connection out to a "Device Cloud".

A Device Cloud is a site such as [ThingSpeak](http://www.thingspeak.com) or the [iDigi Device Cloud](http://www.idigi.com) which are free services that allow two-way communications with remote devices (even through firewalls).  Your website or smartphone then speaks to the Device Cloud using simple web-services which in turn speaks to the XBee Gateway and all of your XBee or ZigBee devices.

Using this pattern you can speak to your XBee or ZigBee devices no matter where they are in the world.

Comment: Maybe I post a question later, but you could point me to a tutorial or so, where I can find how to use a Four Faith Zigbee (8914 E) and a Four Faith Router (F8434 Which is capable to communicate with Zigbee devices) to control a device through a Java app.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is a little unclear. One very important thing to remember is that WiFi uses a lot more power than ZigBee. If you need a mobile device (like a remote control) to operate for months or years on set of AAA batteries then WiFi is not a good choice.

If you clarify your setup I can provide you with a more detailed answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late response; I edited my original question to (hopefully) give some clarification as to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing do a board for this, using two Digi rf modules: a Wifi communicating with a XBee.